# Return 1 result per left join

Tags: sql, join, greatest-n-per-group

Currently I am performing a left join on two tables. The first table has an id and a persons name, the second table has an id, the id of a person from table 1, and then a timestamp (of a flight).

```
People                             Flights
id   |  name             id   |   person_id   | time
------------             ---------------------------
1       Dave              1         1          1284762115
2       Becky             2         1          1284787352
                          3         2          1284772629
                          4         2          1286432934
                          5         1          1283239480
```

When I perform my left join, I get a list of people and their flight times, but what I would like is just the list of people with the flight time **with the highest ID**

I have been using

```
   SELECT p.id, p.name max(f.time) 
     FROM People p 
LEFT JOIN Flights f ON p.id = f.person_id
 GROUP BY p.id, p.name
```

However, this just gives me the LAST flight time, rather than the last flight time uploaded into the system (ie, highest ID).

```
1 Dave  1284787352
2 Becky 1286432934
```

So to reiterate, I would like to see the name of the person, along with the flight time of their last UPLOADED (highest ID) flight time.

```
1 Dave  1283239480
2 Becky 1286432934
```

Comment: Maybe I'm way to tired, but can't you select `max(f.id)` instead of `max(f.time)`?

Comment: No, it doesn't work unfortunately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT p.id,
       p.name,
       f.time
  FROM PEOPLE p
  JOIN FLIGHTS f ON f.person_id = p.id
  JOIN (SELECT f.person_id,
               MAX(f.id) AS max_id
          FROM FLIGHTS f
      GROUP BY f.person_id) x ON x.person_id = f.person_id
                             AND x.max_id = f.id
```

If you are using a database that supports analytics:

```
SELECT p.id,
       p.name,
       x.time
  FROM PEOPLE p
  JOIN (SELECT f.person_id,
               f.time,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY f.person_id
                                     ORDER BY f.id DESC) AS rk
          FROM FLIGHTS f) x ON x.person_id = p.id
                           AND x.rk = 1
```

If you want people, including those without flights:

```
   SELECT p.id,
          p.name,
          f.time
     FROM PEOPLE p
LEFT JOIN FLIGHTS f ON f.person_id = p.id
     JOIN (SELECT f.person_id,
                  MAX(f.id) AS max_id
             FROM FLIGHTS f
         GROUP BY f.person_id) x ON x.person_id = f.person_id
                                AND x.max_id = f.id
```

...and the analytic version:

```
   SELECT p.id,
          p.name,
          x.time
     FROM PEOPLE p
LEFT JOIN (SELECT f.person_id,
                  f.time,
                  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY f.person_id
                                        ORDER BY f.id DESC) AS rk
             FROM FLIGHTS f) x ON x.person_id = p.id
                              AND x.rk = 1
```

Comment: Right on the money! Thanks Ponies, I wasn't even close with what I had   =(

Comment: This will drop out anyone who doesn't have a flight; use a left join rather than inner per his original query

Comment: Ah, for my particular use -this- time I want to drop out anyone without a flight time, however, in the future this may not be the case. 

In that instance, you are saying change both joins to Left joins?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like the below. group by the person_id and select the max id then use that list to select from the flights. This is my first thought there may be a more efficent way.

EDITED:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name MAX(f.time)  
     FROM People p  
LEFT JOIN Flights f ON p.id = f.person_id 
WHERE f.id in(SELECT MAX(id) FROM flights GROUP BY person_id)
```

Comment: #1052 - Column 'id' in IN/ALL/ANY subquery is ambiguous